Error in GDAL pixel function used in VRT
I am trying to translate a vrt to geotiff using gdal_translate in a way that the overlapping areas will get max value from overlapping pixels.
Taking reference from this question, I am doing like below.
  <PixelFunctionType>max</PixelFunctionType>
  <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
  <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
    import numpy as np
    def max(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
        max_values = np.full(in_ar[0].shape, -np.inf)
        for i in range(len(in_ar)):
            max_values = np.maximum(max_values, in_ar[i])
        np.copyto(out_ar, max_values)
    ]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>
    <NoDataValue>-9999</NoDataValue>

While trying to translate it like,
gdal_translate --config GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON YES hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.vrt hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.tif -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co BIGTIFF=YES

I am getting error as,
Input file size is 25247, 27057
0ERROR 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdal_vrt_module_0x296d860", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy

So I tried to modify the pixel function as (added the path for numpy module),
  <PixelFunctionType>max</PixelFunctionType>
  <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
  <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
    import sys
    module_path="/mnt/opt/Centos7/languages/python3/Python-3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/"
    sys.path.append(module_path)
    import numpy as np
    def max(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
        max_values = np.full(in_ar[0].shape, -np.inf)
        for i in range(len(in_ar)):
            max_values = np.maximum(max_values, in_ar[i])
        np.copyto(out_ar, max_values)
    ]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>
    <NoDataValue>-9999</NoDataValue>

But still getting the same error.
One work around I tried is, not using the numpy module at all like,
  <PixelFunctionType>max</PixelFunctionType>
  <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
  <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[
def max(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
    max_values = [[-float('inf')] * len(in_ar[0][0]) for _ in range(len(in_ar[0]))]
    # Iterate over each array in in_ar
    for array in in_ar:
        for i in range(len(array)):
            for j in range(len(array[i])):
                # Update max_values with the maximum value
                max_values[i][j] = max(max_values[i][j], array[i][j])
    # Copy max_values to out_ar
    for i in range(len(max_values)):
        for j in range(len(max_values[i])):
            out_ar[i][j] = max_values[i][j]
    ]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>
    <NoDataValue>-9999</NoDataValue>

But, interestingly, still getting the same error! So, I am guessing the numpy module is getting used elsewhere.
Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to solve this?
I am using python3/3.9.5 (see the edited info below and when I load numpy module interactively, it's getting loaded.
EDITS:
Based on the comment I have done following modifications:
Using python2/2.7.14 now.
Running as bellow
module add python2
gdal_translate --config GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON YES hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.vrt hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.tif -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co BIGTIFF=YES --config PYTHONSO /usr/lib64/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so --config CPL_DEBUG ON

Now, getting another error;
GDAL: GDALOpen(hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.vrt, this=0x2276960) succeeds as VRT.
Input file size is 25247, 27057
0GDAL: GDALDefaultOverviews::OverviewScan()
GTiff: File being created as a BigTIFF.
GDAL: GDAL_CACHEMAX = 4825 MB
GDAL: GDALDatasetCopyWholeRaster(): 25247*9 swaths, bInterleave=0
ERROR 5: VRTDerivedRasterBand::IRasterIO:Derived band pixel function 'max' not registered.

GDAL: GDALClose(hu_205.100.maxh_try_3.vrt, this=0x2276960)

Why is it saying bandfunction not registered?
python version is python2/2.7.14 and gdal version is gdal/2.1.2.

Have you checked the methods in the docs? https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/vrt.html#linking-mechanism-to-a-python-interpreter

What I can understand is that this option can point to the Python library name, either as a short name (e.g., libpython3.10.so) or a full path (e.g., /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.1. I am giving full path. I am understanding it correctly? @user2856

Make sure you point to the same python version that numpy is installed in. i.e. if you want to use numpy that's in /mnt/opt/Centos7/languages/python3/Python-3.9.5/lib/python3.9/site-packages, ensure the same python version is used by GDAL, either by setting PYTHONSO or adjusting your PATH.  As the docs note: "Enabling debug information (CPL_DEBUG=ON) will show which Python version is used"

Thanks for the comments. I have tried to add the debug option and some other options. Please look through the edited info.

GDAL 2.1 is too old. From the docs "Starting with GDAL 2.2, in addition to pixel functions written in C/C++ ..., it is possible to use pixel functions written in Python."
